# USB flash drive's capacity 2% smaller than advertized. Is this normal?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, disk-space

I bought a USB flash drive. It has 4.5/5 stars on Amazon with 2000 ratings. The packaging says `128 GB`. However, as I'm formatting it using the `Disks` utility on Linux, it tells me that the drive is only `125,829,120,000` **bytes**. Is this normal?

[image]

---

Note that the utility spells out the actual number of bytes. This does not seem to be a case of the 1000 vs 1024 mix-up. If it were, it would be 7% short instead (`1e9 / 1024^3 = 0.93`)

Also note that the filesystem size (NTFS) is only `1MB = 0.001%` smaller than the drive size.

---

This was actually a package with 2 drives, and they seem to be identical.

Comment: Could be a case of marketing rounding-up the capacity to a power-of-two.  The capacity of storage devices have typically been manipulated to advertise the largest possible number.  There used to be the unformatted versus formatted controversy.  Then the 1024 versus 1000 base for "KB".

Comment: Your post would be less confusing if the flash drive contained no partitions.  Then there would simply be just the capacity of the entire drive to focus on.

Comment: Observation: you got `120*1000*1024*1024`.

Comment: They must be using a [drivemaker's GB](https://xkcd.com/394/)

Comment: The most likely reason is actually spare blocks/room for wear leveling, but that’s nearly impossible to prove or disprove.

Comment: @DanielB Or it's just a better fake than what you are used to.

Comment: Yeah, no. Flash memory chips come in fixed sizes. Evil guys can't just say "oh I know I'll remove 2 GB to save some money". It's not possible. A USB flash drive will have one flash chips, some expensive high-performance ones may have two.

Comment: @DanielB Are you are assuming that brand names and scammers use the exact same chips? They do not: https://www.usbmakers.com/what-are-the-different-grades-of-usb-flash-drives/

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be common on flash media.  I've got a 256GB stick here that is 247,593,959,424 bytes (90.07%), and a 64GB SSD that is 62,813,896,704 bytes (91.4%).

I suspect the cited size is the chip size (and is binary), and that the actual size is after the wear leveling overhead and replacement blocks are removed.

Comment: Maybe they are counterfeit?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, on every flash drive, there is some data allocated by the system (boot data, file system...) and the user can't use that space

Comment: https://promotionaldrives.com/blog/why-do-usb-flash-drives-show-a-lower-storage-capacity-when-plugged-into-a-computer/

Comment: https://www.scienceabc.com/innovation/why-do-hard-drivesusb-drives-show-less-space-than-advertised-when-plugged-in.html

Comment: The explanations linked in the above comments do not apply in my case. The utility spells out the actual number of bytes: `125,...`.

Comment: yes, there is about one megabyte according to the screenshot. What about the other missing ~2GB?